# Can I link to a wordpress page and have it already scrolled down to some part that I want?

Tags: html, wordpress, scroll, hyperlink, focus

on my homepage, I have a section with services, which is somewhere lower, near the end of the page.
is it possible to make a link in the menu, that would open the homepage and automatically scroll down to that services part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, if you link a page and put a DOM id at the end of the link.

example:

1) link

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/link#here">Go</a>
```

2) page

```
<div id="head-of-the-page">blah</div>

 .... content goes here ....

<div id="here">focus gets here</div>
```

Then, you will get to the point right after the click